# getting Salesforce ContentNote.Content from SOQL

Tags: salesforce, soql, jsforce

We are working with SOQL to interact with Salesforce.  Consider the very simple query:

```
      select Id, Content, TextPreview, Field
      from ContentNote
      limit 100
```

Per their documentation [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm). `Content` should be the rich text -- but what w are getting back a URL pointing to the content.  Which requires us to do *n+1* queries.

The response we get looks something like:

```
{
  attributes: {
    type: 'ContentNote',
    url: '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ContentNote/asdfasdf0707234sdsdf'
  },
  Id: '0692L000008xwLMQAY',
  Content: '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ContentNote/asdfasdf0707234sdsdf/Content',
  TextPreview: 'please give jonathan a call'
}
```

Note we are leveraging jsforce for our API access.

Has anyone worked around this?

### FYI

[image]

Comment: I'm going to flag it as possible duplicate. Check if my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60284736/313628 helps you. `ContentNote` is technically stored as `ContentDocument`/`ContentVersion` with special type so probably you're hitting same thing. "Deal with it" (extra API call per document) or see if you can switch over to SOAP API and decode base64 payload. No idea if jsforce can be easily switched over to SOAP though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get base64 data of file from Salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60283198/get-base64-data-of-file-from-salesforce)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ContentNote> cn = [SELECT Id, Content, Title FROM ContentNote ];
for(ContentNote ecn : cn){
    String myString = ecn.Content.toString();
    String extractedText = myString.stripHtmlTags();
    System.debug(extractedText);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**