# How to get binarydata from ContentVersion based on Case ID

Tags: salesforce, soql

I need help to make a soql to get the images from ContentVersion based on caseId

We have 3 objects:
ContentDocument
ContentVersion
ContentDocumentlink

ContentDocument is parent of ContentVersion and ContentDocumentLink

ContentVersion has versiondata(that is binary data)
ContentDocumentLink having case id(Fieldname  is LinkedEntityId)

I need to create a  SOQL that provides version data of ContentVersion based on linkedentityID ( case- ID) when I use this query

select versiondata from contentversion where contentdocumentid in(select contentdocumentid from contentdocumentlink where linkedentityid in(select id from case))

Than it is giving the error like
Entity 'contentdocumentlink' is not supported for semi join inner selects

It is giving error like semi join is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

This works with any id (any object that you marked as allow attachments)

```
SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData 
FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE LinkedEntityId = '...'
```

Or top-down (useful if you need multiple records and their files)

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject, 
    (SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData FROM ContentDocumentLinks)
FROM Case
WHERE Id = '...'
```

Comment: If I am using  this query SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData 
FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE LinkedEntityId in(select id from case) than it is giving me object form soql so I want to know what it will return ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData.  I need binary data from Content version based on case id but I need to use only with soql

Comment: "object" as in useless JavaScript "[Object object]"? Run it from sfdx, data loader or workbench.developerforce.com to see the result properly. What you'll get depends on API used. REST API will have a link to retrieve the raw binary, SOAP API (like python's "simple Salesforce" library) will give back base64-encoded file payload

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60284736/313628 for more info