# Unable to Locate Object Link for PDF Downloads in Salesforce via Power Automate - How to Traverse from Opportunities to Content Documents?

Tags: salesforce, power-automate, salesforce-lightning

I start at the Opportinities object, get the id of quotes, pass quotes documents and go to content Documents, but I can't find the object link so I can download the attached pdfs.
I'm doing everything by Power Automate

I tried in several ways, I tried to get to Attachment, Documents and I couldn't

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely your files are stored as Attachments, that table is old and more fit to Salesforce Classic. You could try `SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = '006...'` but I'd expect 0 results.

Use the approach from my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74897406/313628 (I can't mark the question as duplicate because nobody upvoted it ;))

Your actual payload is hidden in [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) table, VersionData field. It's a related list under ContentDocument but for your purposes probably fetching

```
SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData 
FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE LinkedEntityId = '006...'
```

is enough.

Now... what you will see in `VersionData` depends on which API you are using. Over REST API the field will simply contain 1 more link you need to pull (HTTP GET) to get the raw binary/text payload. Over SOAP API it'll return and XML document with the payload as 1 of the fields, base64-encoded. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60284736/313628