# Salesforce jsforce download and base64 conversion of staticresource body

Tags: javascript, salesforce, jsforce

Javascript novice and am stuck trying to convert a staticresource record body to a parseable string, and hoping someone might know how to proceed?

I have retrieved the static resource successfully using jsforce library. The resource is a csv file, and the body attribute of the result returned presents as a url ie. Body
:
"/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/StaticResource/resourceId/Body"

I tried to prepend the domain and url together and do this, but nothing happened..no errors, no console output; maybe the wrong approach?

```
// res.records[0].Body definitely returns the url for the body
// I have put 'domain' in place of my actual salesforce domain :)
const url =  'https://domain.lightning.force.com' + res.records[0].Body;
fetch(url)
.then(res => {console.log(res); });
```

Beyond this point I'm stuck - I've not been able to figure out how to get any further. Any suggestions on how to get from this url to actually having a usable result would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set a HTTP header `Authorisation` with value `Bearer {session id sometimes referred to as access token}`. You'll get back the raw payload.

It looks like you got a REST API result (SOAP API would return the base64-encoded thing as is, not a link to actual content) so hopefully you're already aware of that setting the header and have a valid session id?

See also my other answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60284736/313628

**Edit:**

I don't think you should be using "lightning" url. Use what came back from login request / what you see on login page. Exact url will vary depending on production/sandbox and whether your admin started testing "enhanced domains" SF update. You'll get raw binary, not base64

Do this HTTP request in programming language of your choice

1. login (obtain instance url and access_token a.k.a. session id)
2. and then

"raw HTTP"

```
GET /services/data/v56.0/sobjects/StaticResource/0815r000000GmvmAAC/Body HTTP/1.1
Host: (redacted).my.salesforce.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer 00D(redacted)
```

cURL

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://(redacted).my.salesforce.com/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/StaticResource/0815r000000GmvmAAC/Body' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 00D(redacted)'
```

Here's my Postman, request was sent to a sandbox:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for proposing an answer. Really appreciated!  I am passing in a token now and the response body is not the content hoped for; it is just the url originally passed in ie 'Body
: 
"/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/StaticResource/resourceId/Body" ... it is telling me the file is csv and content length is 44 bytes which is correct, but I cannot get the base64 encoded body anywhere. Am obviously missing something fundamental but cannot figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: thanks for the additional advice!. Was enough for me to muddle through and get the outcome required.  For anyone that reads this thread, I did use fetch and upon receipt of response leveraged a reader stream to get from blob to text.

Comment: Done! no vote required :)

Answer (score 1):

Code sample for future reference - (no vote requested...)

```
async function getFile(fileId) {
  let url = '/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/StaticResource/'.concat(fileId,'/Body');
  let res = '';

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+accessToken
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    return new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
        return pump();
        function pump() {
          return reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
            // When no more data needs to be consumed, close the stream
            if (done) {
              controller.close();
              return;
            }
            // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
            controller.enqueue(value);
            return pump();
          });
        }
      }
    })
  })
  // Create a new response out of the stream
  .then((stream) => new Response(stream))
  // Create an object URL for the response
  .then((response) => response.blob())
  .then((blob) => blob.text())
  // Update result
  .then((chunk) => console.log(res = chunk))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```